# Ember Controller Data Accessed From Other Places

Tags: ember.js

I have a websocket connection getting live price data in my application.js controller. I put it in here because I want the connection to initialize and the data to be accessed from any page and not reconnected every page load.

I have no idea how to access this data from other controllers or templates.

2 things I want to do:
1) Check for a value and update a dynamic price on every page in the navigation bar.
2) Access the websocket data in other controllers. I don't know if this would affect the message handler already defined in application.js. I guess the event data should be going into a variable.

application.js

```
headerPrice: 0,

setupWebsocket: function() {
  this._super();
  var socket = this.get('websockets').socketFor('ws://localhost:7000/');
  socket.on('open', this.myOpenHandler, this);
  socket.on('message', this.myMessageHandler, this);
  socket.on('close', function(event) {
    console.log('Websocket closed');
  }, this);
}.on('init'),

myOpenHandler: function(event) {
  console.log('Websocket Opened: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
},

myMessageHandler: function(event) {
  if (event.data == "foo") {
     this.headerPrice = event.data.price;
  };
}
```

}

Comment: Use a service instead!

Comment: Thanks, the was the way to go. Grinded through and got it working while learning a bunch along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with an initializer and service extension (ember-websocket is a service already).

**Initializer:**

```
export function initialize(app) {
  app.register('websocket:main', 'websocket', { instantiate: true, singleton: true });
  app.inject('controller', 'websocket', 'service:websocket');
  app.inject('component', 'websocket', 'service:websocket');
}

export default {
  name: 'websocket',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

**Service:**

```
import websocket from 'ember-websockets/services/websockets';

export default websocket.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    var socket = this.socketFor('ws://localhost:7000', ['echo-protocol']);
    console.log('initializing websocket...');
    socket.on('open', this.myOpenHandler, this);
    socket.on('message', this.myMessageHandler, this);
    .....
```

Comment: Tiny suggestion, use the `inject.service` API to explicitly instead of injecting in an initializer. You can see which services are available to the controller when you open the file, and you can avoid overriding properties.